# Multiple events in the same p:ajax in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to have multiple events in the same *p:ajax*?

Something like this:

```
<p:ajax event="firstEvent,secondEvent..." listener="doSomething();" />
```

Comment: Three letters... T R Y...  (and 'doSomething();' will never work. If you create pseudo code, do it at least a little better ;-))

Comment: Hey thanks, but the point here was to show the definition of event defining or what I mean. Of course, who did try this has found it doesn't work. The question is about the existence of some form of naming like in this pseudo-code. Sorry if I was not enough clear.

Comment: Well, if it does not work and you don't find any documentation about this, tge only thing you can do is try with a different plain jsf example. If it does not work there either, it just might be that it is not supported. The specs of jsf are open btw

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but it seems that's not possible: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=8902#p8902

Answer (score 12):

I know it's late, but I found a way to do this. You only need to put N tags of p:ajax, i.e:

```
<p:calendar id="startDate" value="#{bean.date}"
    pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
    validator="#{bean.checkDate}">
    <p:ajax update="dialog:endDate" event="dateSelect" /> 
    <p:ajax update="dialog:endDate" event="keyup" /> 
</p:calendar>
```

Comment: The question: _"Multiple events in the **same p:ajax** in PrimeFaces"_. Your answer is the normal way and yes, sure that will work. The question was about doing it a completely different way with using just one `p:ajax` tag

Comment: It's a useful answer.

Comment: I just wanted confirmation - and that helped me. You know, separate by space, colon, comma, ... just had to be sure it was not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Faced with the same problem and came across this post. After trivial investigation, the "multiple events in the same p:ajax"-approach will not work. It is not supported at least for the tested Primefaces 5.3 version.
An Exception like this will arise:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.TagException: <p:ajax> Event:firstEvent,secondEvent is not supported.
```

Some source code from the `AbstractBehaviorHandler` class:

```
 ClientBehaviorHolder holder = (ClientBehaviorHolder) parent;

    String eventName = getEventName();

    if (null == eventName) {
        eventName = holder.getDefaultEventName();
        if (null == eventName) {
            throw new TagException(this.tag, "Event attribute could not be determined: "  + eventName);
        }
    } else {
        Collection<String> eventNames = holder.getEventNames();
        if (!eventNames.contains(eventName)) {
            throw new TagException(this.tag,  "Event:" + eventName + " is not supported.");
        }
    }
```