# Is there a HTML5 event "oninput" for <f:ajax>?

Tags: jsf

I have in JSF 2.3 a html5 number-input and currently the ajax-listener is triggered for every change-event. but the listener should also fire immediately when i manually change the input-value by typing something, so i would need both; the onchange and a keyup or the new HTML5 "oninput"-event. Is there a way to handle this requirement with the ajax-listener?

```
<h:inputText id="minRating" value="#{bankingConroller.minRating}"  
             pt:type="number" pt:min="0" pt:step="1">

   <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bankingConroller.setRatings()}" 
           execute="minRating" />
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: can you put multiple f:ajax tags for the same input field? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38319944/3795036

Comment: oh, didn't thought about that. this does the job.